# Firebird Embedded and Entity Framework ditch special characters

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, firebird

### Overview

I have a very specific problem with the EntityFramework.Firebird-Provider.

When I try to update a property of an entity with the EntityFramework, special characters (like ö, ü, ä & ß) get converted to dots. However, this only happens when I use the EmbeddedServer functionality of Firebird.

### Steps to reproduce

Create a simple Firebird-Database with one table.
Here is the DDL of my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
  ID                  INTEGER      NOT NULL,
  NAME1               VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  NAME2               VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE ISO8859_1,
  STREET              VARCHAR(50)  COLLATE ISO8859_1,
 CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Create a small C# Test-Project and add the NuGet-Packages

- FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
- EntityFramework.Firebird

You have to update the EntityFramework afterwards! I used Version 6.1.3 for this.

Add a simple Entity, TypeConfiguration and DbContext as following:

```cs
public class SimpleCustomer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleCustomerTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SimpleCustomer>
{
    public SimpleCustomerTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("CUSTOMER");

        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        this.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        this.Property(e => e.Name1).HasColumnName("NAME1");
        this.Property(e => e.Name2).HasColumnName("NAME2");
        this.Property(e => e.Street).HasColumnName("STREET");
    }
}

public class FbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SimpleCustomer> SimpleCustomers { get; set; }

    public FbContext(DbConnection connection) : base(connection, false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<FbContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SimpleCustomerTypeConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When you now try to update a property like Street with the DbContext, e.g.:

```
using (var connection = new FbConnection(@"User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; Database=TEST.FDB; CharSet=ISO8859_1; ServerType=1; Pooling=false;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    
    using (var context = new FbContext(connection))
    {
        var writeCustomer = context.SimpleCustomers.Find(1);
        writeCustomer.Street = @"Schloßallee 34";
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

the Street got saved as **Schlo.allee 34** in the Database.

### Additional Info

Here is some additional information I managed to figure out:

- It only happens if you use the embedded Firebird server. (*ServerType=1*)
- Changing the CharSet or converting the encoding to something else like Unicode or Windows1252 doesn't seem to change a thing.

  - Except for when you change the Connection-CharSet to UTF8: Then you get two dots instead of one. **Yaaay! \o/**
- The update works perfectly fine when you use a classic SQL Update-Command like e.g.:

  ```
   using (var connection = new FbConnection(@"User=SYSDBA; Password=masterkey; Database=TEST.FDB; CharSet=ISO8859_1; ServerType=1; Pooling=false;"))
   {
       connection.Open();

       var command = connection.CreateCommand();
       command.CommandText = @"UPDATE CUSTOMER SET STREET = @STREET WHERE ID = @ID";
       command.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter("STREET", FbDbType.VarChar, 50) { Value = "Schloßallee 34" });
       command.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter("ID", FbDbType.Integer) { Value = 1 });

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
  ```

Comment: Does your embedded install contain the `icu` files and the `intl` folder? If not, part of the character set support is missing.

Comment: My embedder installation contains the Intl-Folder with the unedited fbintl.conf and fbintl.dll in it, as well as the icuuc30.dll, icudt30.dll and icuin30.dll.

Comment: Yes, and I just realized you said it works fine when using a normal update. Not sure what the problem might be, because I would expect that to work the same in both cases (and I would not expect there to be a difference between Embedded and normal server in this). Which version of FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and EntityFramework.Firebird are you using?

Comment: I use  FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient and EntityFramework.Firebird in Version 5.0.5 and Firebird Embedded in Version 2.5.5. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.